# "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity " The app does not start and shows a blank screen

Tags: android, kotlin

I am novice to android. I have been working on a simple app. This app has only one activity. The activity contains a Button. The button when clicked shows a toast text.

The following is my `activity_main.xml` file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Text_textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="34sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.528"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.375" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/changeText_Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/button_text"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:background="#FFC0CB"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.568"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.641" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And this is my MainActivity.kt file

```
package com.androidcreate.myexperimentsapp

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    var text : TextView = findViewById(R.id.Text_textView)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.changeText_Button)


        button.setOnClickListener {
            changeText()
        }
    }

    private fun changeText() {
        val toast = Toast.makeText(
            applicationContext,
            "This is a message displayed in a Toast",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        )

        toast.show()
    }
}
```

When I run the app the app does not load. I shows a blank black screen.
The following is the logcat:

```
=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.internal.server.HardwareArProviderService }: process is bad
2020-09-14 13:57:42.606 556-580/? I/ActivityManager: Exiting empty application process 0:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a102 (null)
2020-09-14 13:57:42.610 556-577/? E/ActivityManager: Failure starting process com.google.android.gms.persistent
    java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.google.android.gms is currently frozen!
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:4451)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:1757)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:2319)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:2441)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3148)
        at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.bringUpServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:2946)
        at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.bindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:2062)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.bindIsolatedService(ActivityManagerService.java:15158)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1833)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1783)
        at com.android.server.ServiceWatcher.rebind(ServiceWatcher.java:339)
        at com.android.server.ServiceWatcher.onBestServiceChanged(ServiceWatcher.java:310)
        at com.android.server.ServiceWatcher.onBindingDied(ServiceWatcher.java:391)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1950)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1986)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
2020-09-14 13:57:42.610 556-577/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.google.android.gms appid=10102 user=0: start failure
2020-09-14 13:57:42.611 556-577/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{946b99 u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.network.NetworkLocationService}
2020-09-14 13:57:42.612 556-577/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10102 for service Intent { act=com.android.location.service.v3.NetworkLocationProvider cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.network.NetworkLocationService }: process is bad
2020-09-14 13:57:42.613 556-580/? I/ActivityManager: Exiting empty application process 0:com.google.android.gms.persistent/u0a102 (null)
2020-09-14 13:57:42.617 556-577/? E/ActivityManager: Failure starting process com.google.android.gms.persistent
    java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.google.android.gms is currently frozen!
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:4451)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:1757)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:2319)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:2441)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.startProcessLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:3148)
        at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.bringUpServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:2946)
        at com.android.server.am.ActiveServices.bindServiceLocked(ActiveServices.java:2062)
        at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.bindIsolatedService(ActivityManagerService.java:15158)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1833)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindServiceAsUser(ContextImpl.java:1783)
        at com.android.server.ServiceWatcher.rebind(ServiceWatcher.java:339)
        at com.android.server.ServiceWatcher.onBestServiceChanged(ServiceWatcher.java:310)
        at com.android.server.ServiceWatcher.onBindingDied(ServiceWatcher.java:391)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(LoadedApk.java:1950)
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(LoadedApk.java:1986)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
        at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:44)
2020-09-14 13:57:42.617 556-577/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.google.android.gms appid=10102 user=0: start failure
2020-09-14 13:57:42.618 556-577/? I/ActivityManager:   Force stopping service ServiceRecord{d84426a u0 com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.fused.FusedLocationService}
2020-09-14 13:57:42.618 556-577/? W/ActivityManager: Unable to launch app com.google.android.gms/10102 for service Intent { act=com.android.location.service.FusedLocationProvider cmp=com.google.android.gms/com.google.android.location.fused.FusedLocationService }: process is bad
2020-09-14 13:57:42.622 556-577/? E/ActivityManager: Failure starting process com.google.android.gms.persistent
    java.lang.SecurityException: Package com.google.android.gms is currently frozen!
        at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.checkPackageStartable(PackageManagerService.java:4451)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:1757)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:2319)
        at com.android.server.am.ProcessList.startProcessLocked(ProcessList.java:2441)
```

Please help me out. Thank you

Comment: is your Activity declared in manifest.xml ?

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure you have registered you're activity in the `manifest.xml` file, something like:

```xml
<application
    ..........................
    ..........................
    ..........................
    ..........................
    ..........................
    ..........................>
     
    <activity android:name=".mainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
   
</application>
```

Then, You're committing a mistake by accessing `Text_textView` view before it's been created since the views that in the `activity_main.xml` are connected with `Activity` class at`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`.

If you need to make a view as a property (in this case class-scope variable), then you may follow these approaches:

1. Just use the Kotlin view extension feature (the easiest way).
2. Mark the property as a lazy initialized or late initialized.
3. Mark the property as a nullable type (bad approach).

**Kotlin view extension feature**

Which is the most elegant solution you can access any view by its id directly inside the activity, for example, you can access the button immediately using it's id `changeText_Button`:

```kotlin
//***Delete the line below***.
var text : TextView = findViewById(R.id.Text_textView)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        //***Delete the line below***.
        val button : Button = findViewById(R.id.changeText_Button)


        changeText_Button.setOnClickListener {
            changeText()
        }
}
```

**Using Lazy initialization:**

In this approach, the property (local variable) will have value first time accessed not in the declaration site, so in this way, we can make a view as global property and  for example:

```kotlin
val text : TextView by lazy { findViewById(R.id.Text_textView) }

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        ...

}
```